# error undeploy tomcat7.0.54 + jsf 2.2

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
jul 09, 2014 9:22:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.
WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [/jsf] appears to have started a thread named
 [Mojarra-WebResourceMonitor-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it.
 This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Comment: This is a memory leak issue its not specific to technology or server. Did you tried to run a simple hello world application in your server ? Try it and tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us something about your application - did you start a thread manually, as hinted in the exception? This is something, you should not do in Java EE, since components (e.g. JSF components) are handled by the container. If you do it manually, they won't be destroyed, thus may lead to memory leaks.

Comment: javaweb with jsf 2.2, primefaces5.0,hibernate 4.3.5 tomcat 7.0.54

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Apache Tomcat Server so you could change the version of Tomcat Server. Apache Tomcat's current version 8.0.9 has this problem but **8.0.3.0** doesn't have. I am using Netbeans IDE (8.1) so Apache Tomcat 8.0.3.0 came with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a ContextListener beeing added twice to the ServletContext:

com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

It is once added by the com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer
and secondly by org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer

To prevent JasperInitializer adding the listener, you have to tell it to skip TLD scanning in javax.faces*.jar:

In your context.xml, add:

```
<JarScanner>
  <JarScanFilter defaultPluggabilityScan="false"
    pluggabilityScan="${tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan}, javax.faces-*.jar"
    tldSkip="${tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip}, javax.faces-*.jar" />
</JarScanner>
```